Error pulling from Docker Hub: failed to verify certificate
Pulling from Docker Hub I get:

error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2024-04-18T15:21:17+02:00 is after 2021-09-30T14:01:15Z

I get this error on two different CentOS 7 servers with the same timestamp "2021-09-30T14:01:15Z", my third server works.

The real time clock is correct.
I'm using root.
I have not an /etc/docker/certs.d folder, nor /root/.docker/ca.pem.
I have tried to update Docker to the latest release.
Google results have not
helped.

Any suggestion?

This date 2021-09-30 with a SSL issue involved rings a bell. Maybe your servers are affected later by the 2021 Let's Encrypt DST Root CA X3 certificate expiration. Because on 30th September 2021, the root certificate that Let's Encrypt was currently using in its certificate chain, has expired. see

I have just tried yum install ca-certificates and I still get that error.

Check DNS and the returned certificate. nslookup registry-1.docker.io and openssl s_client -connect registry-1.docker.io:443 -showcerts </dev/null.

After having updated the certificates I have also rebooted the servers and now I can pull.  Thanks.

I encouter this problem in vmware with centos7. I simply "continue" system which hung before and long time no use. After reboot system, the problem gone. Maybe not in your case.
